# IIS logging - cs-uri-stem doesn't match known content

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I'm trying to locate the source files being used when loading a page through IIS.

The developer console in Chrome and also the cs-uri-stem IIS logs show the location, however I am unable to find that specific folder/file they both reference within the root of the site.

I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious. If someone could point me in the right direction on this, I'd really appreciate it.

I'm using IIS 8.5.

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing pointing to the source file, as there can be no mapping between URLs and source files (ASP.NET MVC for example).

Comment: cs-uri-stem has nothing to do with source files, what kind of file do you want to find?